# Angular & Electron - IPC communication between main & render processes

Tags: angular, electron

There are small model:

```
export class SettingsModel {
  DbFileName: string;
}
```

Main process:

```
ipcMain.on('getSettings', function(event) {
    event.sender.send('resultSettings', 'Test settings');
});
```

IpcService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ElectronService } from 'ngx-electron';

@Injectable()
export class IpcService {
  constructor(private _electronService: ElectronService) {}

  public on(channel: string, listener: Function): void {
    this._electronService.ipcRenderer.on(channel, listener);
  }

  public send(channel: string, ...args): void {
    this._electronService.ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
  }
}
```

And finally angular component:

```
export class SettingsComponent {
  constructor(private _electronService: ElectronService, private _db: DbService, private _ipc: IpcService) {
    this.Settings = new SettingsModel();
    console.log("1:" + this.Settings)
    _ipc.send('getSettings');
    console.log("2:" + this.Settings)
    _ipc.on('resultSettings', this._updateSettings);
    console.log("3:" + this.Settings)
  }

  private _updateSettings(evt: any, result: string) {
    console.log("4:" + result);
    console.log("5:" + this.Settings);
    this.Settings.DbFileName = result;
  }

  Settings: SettingsModel;
}
```

Result chromium log:

```
1:[object Object]
2:[object Object]
3:[object Object]
4:Test settings
5:undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'DbFileName' of undefined
```

It seems that IPC works fine, but for some reason when I get the response I have a different instance of the SettingsComponent class. I don't know why and how to manage it. Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is related with neither angular nor electon nor IPC, but with TypeScript.

```
public on(channel: string, listener: Function): void {
  this._electronService.ipcRenderer.on(channel, listener);
}
```

I have to use arrow expression `=>`:

```
public on(channel: string, listener: Function): void {
  this._electronService.ipcRenderer.on(channel, (evt, args) => listener(evt, arg));
}
```

and

```
_ipc.on('resultSettings', (evt, args) => this._updateSettings(evt, args));
```