# How do I share config between electron main and renderer procs?

Tags: webpack, configuration, electron

I have an electron app. The renderer process shows a Vue.js app which is created using webpack. It contains a few config settings that are packaged up along with all the other code as part of the bundle. I need for the main process to get access to these config settings as well. What's the best way to do this?

One consideration is that the environment (`development`, `production`, etc) is chosen at build time. So which config settings are bundled up into the html app is determined when you webpack it, not at runtime by `NODE_ENV` or similar.

I'm currently using the [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin) to copy the appropriate config files over to another folder during the build and the main process is reading the config out of this folder. It works but it's a bit clunky and magical.

I supposed I could also move all the config data into the main process code and provide it to the renderer process via ipc upon start up. Also seems a bit clunky.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular & Electron - IPC communication between main & render processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49760019/angular-electron-ipc-communication-between-main-render-processes)

Comment: No other better way then passing data at startup to renderer process using IPC communication.